# Newbie: How to use QMAKE to compile and install FaustLive on Ubuntu Studio 20.04? Can't create Makefile with qmake w/ linux-g++

Tags: software-installation, compiling, g++, makefile, qmake

FaustLive is an open source prototyping environment for Faust (open source, compiled audio programming language). Here is FaustLive's GitHub: https://github.com/grame-cncm/faustlive

After successfully compiling and installing Faust through the terminal, I'm having trouble doing the same with FaustLive on my Ubuntu Studio 20.04. Here are their build instructions: https://github.com/grame-cncm/faustlive/tree/master/Build

I have all their listed prerequisite packages installed (as far as I can tell, as a terminal/linux novice). I'm stuck at their "Project generation" step. After I changed directory to the FaustLive folder where I cloned their github as per instructions, I'm trying to execute:

`$ qmake -spec /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++/qplatformdefs.h`

When executing, qmake just repeats this:

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++/qplatformdefs.h:3: Extra characters after test expression.`
It repeats with h:3, to h:59, skipping a few lines in between. It's final output is:
`Error processing project file: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++/qplatformdefs.h`

What do I do from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PKGBUILD from [ArchLinux](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=faustlive-git) we can get the following method for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get install build-essential qt5-default faust qrencode libjack-jackd2-dev \
libmicrohttpd-dev liblo-dev libsndfile1-dev libasound2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/grame-cncm/faustlive.git
cd faustlive
git submodule update --init
cd Build

make

sudo cp FaustLive/FaustLive /usr/local/bin
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/applications/
sed "s|Icon=Faustlive|Icon=/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/FaustLive.png|" -i rsrc/FaustLive.desktop
sudo cp rsrc/FaustLive.desktop /usr/local/share/applications/
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps
sudo cp ../Resources/FaustLive.png /usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps
```

As the result you will be able to run FaustLive using its shortcut.

Comment: Thank you, all the lines were executed without a hitch. However, I'm not sure how to run the FaustLive application. When I double click on the FaustLive shared library file in the /Build/FaustLive folder, it asks me to choose an application to open with. How do I run the final app? Edit: I just realized the shared library doesn't have the FaustLive png icon, but 2x2 checker pattern. Perhaps I'm mistaking the shared library file for the app?

Comment: I think I got it! The application is a 'desktop configuration file' type, and is located in ```/faustlive/Build/rsrc/```. Marking it as an executable assigns its logo and double clicking it now runs the app! Only problem now is that newer code doesn't seem to work, as FaustLive throws syntax errors, but that's a separate issue. Thank you!